# Selecting distinct values from joined results in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to access complete data from two tables in mysql and then find distinct values of a column from the resulting set. tried doing with nested query as follows :-

```
Select distinct s.BlockName 
from (SELECT * 
      FROM constucted
      LEFT JOIN required ON constucted.BlockName = required.BlockName 

      UNION

      SELECT * 
      FROM constucted
      RIGHT JOIN required ON constucted.BlockName = required.BlockName
     ) s
```

As mentioned in [Stackoverflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323577/selecting-distinct-values-from-joined-results)
and also tried using the with keyword as follows :-

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM constucted
   LEFT JOIN required ON constucted.BlockName = required.BlockName

   UNION

   SELECT * 
   FROM constucted
   RIGHT JOIN required ON constucted.BlockName = required.BlockName
)
SELECT DISTINCT BlockName
FROM CTE
```

But unable to find the distinct value for the column BlockName unable to prepare a query for the same.

Comment: pls put sample data and expected result. Thanks.

Comment: How your output is wrong? You see duplicates? Missing data? Or receiving en error?

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would seem to be more simply written as:

```
select BlockName 
from constructed
union -- intentional to remove duplicates
select BlockName
from required;
```

Comment: Amazing solution can't believe I banged my head for hours.