# Joining with a distinct column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do I join a table with a distinct value in a SQL view?
My code looks like below

`Select a, b, c, d from TableA inner join TableB on TableA.account = TableB.account`

I want TableB.account to have distinct values when I join the table.

The selected fields(a,b,c,d) do not have to be distinct values.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. Sample data and expected results, along with your attempts will help us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql server select first row from a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344731/sql-server-select-first-row-from-a-group)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting distinct values from joined results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323577/selecting-distinct-values-from-joined-results)

Comment: what I want is to use is a distinct field when I join the table
For example,    
Select a, b, c, d
from Table A
inner join tableB on tableA.account = TableB.account
and I want the TableB.account field to be a distinct value, and the fields in the selected field do not have to be distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT distinct_foo.thing
     , bar.other_things
FROM   (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               thing
        FROM   foo
       ) AS distinct_foo
 INNER
  JOIN bar
    ON bar.thing = distinct_foo.thing
;
```